# django rest framework how to close Self describing APIs browsable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Like the image, I want to close `The browsable API that REST framework provides`.

Click to visit directly the JSON data.

[image]

Comment: Please rewrite your question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `settings.py` file add following code in the section of `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings

```
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
),
```

If you use `BrowsableAPIRenderer`you will see browsable API interface. `JSONRenderer` will show JSON data.